# phpWord generated documents behave different in MSWord and OpenOffice? bug?

Tags: phpword

We are using phpword to generate word documents.
What we have at this moment is the following:
If we use addText() all newlines, tabs, etc. works in Open Office (same as they are in the source xml file) but don't work in MS Word. (There are a few question about this in SO, so we went for the textRun ...)
If we use addTextRun() and addTextBreak(), the linebreaks, tabs, etc. are 
shown in MS Word ... but not in OpenOffice ...
We are generating the document as Word2007

It's disappointing.... We did a lot of test, all with same result.

Is this a known issue? 
does anyone have a solution to have "same/similar" display when opening a document in msword or open office?

---

Here is more info regarding this issue:
We generate a file, and open it on MS Word and Open Office

[Here is what you see in MS Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eytQS.png)

[Here is what you see in OpenOffice or LibreOffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehppy.png)

As you may see, the behavior of text and text-run with linebreaks are the opposite depending which suite you use to open the document.

What we want to accomplish is to create reports based on content retrieved from a data base. This content may may have line breaks, tabs, etc.

As per requested, here is some of our code. We make a wrapper to handle the phpword objects, here are the relevant parts of our code;

```
$this->phpWord = new PhpWord();

function setSectionFromXmlNode($sectionNode, $format = null) {

    $section = $this->phpWord->addSection($format);

    foreach ($sectionNode->text as $textNode) {
        $format = $this->getTextFormatFromXmlNode($textNode);
        $section->addText($textNode, $format);
    }

    foreach ($sectionNode->{'text-run'} as $textRunNode) {
        $format = $this->getTextFormatFromXmlNode($textRunNode);
        $textChunk = $textRunNode->__toString();
        $textlines = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $textChunk);
        $textrun = $section->addTextRun();
        $textrun->addText(array_shift($textlines),$format);
        foreach($textlines as $line) {
            $textrun->addTextBreak();
            $textrun->addText($line,$format);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the xml

```
<document>
    <section>
        <text>This is a new section.
        Spaces, tabs, and linebreaks should be preserved</text>
        <text>
            one
            two
            three lines
        </text>
        <text-run>
        one
        two
        three lines
        </text-run>
    </section>
</document>
```

We received an answer from phpWord supporters.
Here is the link https:// github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1132#issuecomment-335580096 explaining the difference we notice on how paragraphs looks between suites.

Comment: come with some code not just with an idea

Comment: Thanks Dis3buted, just add some more info and images to show our issue